# resizing TelerikDateRangePicker components

Tags: html, css, telerik, blazor

I want to resize input date boxes of TelerikDateRangePicker component in Blazor in order to fit it better in my page. It looks to be a bit long and I want to resize it. This is the original size:
[image]
I tried adding

```
<style>
    .k-floating-label-container {
          width: 140px !important;
     }
</style>
```

to the header of the page when running which made it as follows:
[image]
However, when I do the same in my CSS file and then run the application it goes back to the default. Any idea on this?

Comment: Have you tried `<TelerikDateTimePicker ... Width="140px"></TelerikDateTimePicker>` Is your CSS file that overrides loaded last? Also, Blazor has [CSS isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0) that may help.

Comment: The range picker does not seem to have a width parameter. @op - try adding your CSS rule after the telerik stylesheet. Of that does not help, ask support. Of nothing else, a Width parameter should be added

Comment: Yes, thanks guys, I will contact the support and see how they go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted them and they said: "To resize the inner inputs for the *DateRangePicker* you can use some custom CSS styles. To make cascading easier you can use the Class parameter that is available for the *TelerikDateRangePicker*. To better illustrate the concept, I have created a small sample that you can see from this [REPL link](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/ccEPGuOC49a6jh8a03?_ga=2.248100751.909072660.1643262150-484977459.1640919897), as well as quickly run it to see the rendered result."